# Replicating FileZilla using Windows ftp command

Tags: command-line-interface, ftp

After properly configuring FileZilla to communicate between servers, I tried to automate some transfers using Windows builtin FTP support

```
ftp -s:command.file
```

I replicated FileZilla's client commands verbatim (using *literal*) and I get this weird phenomenon:

Successful transfer using FileZilla

```
(000058) 2009-05-19 18:30:51 - (not logged in) (*.*.*.*)> Connected, sending welcome message...
(000058) 2009-05-19 18:30:51 - (not logged in) (*.*.*.*)> 220 welcome...
(000058) 2009-05-19 18:30:51 - (not logged in) (*.*.*.*)> USER user1
(000058) 2009-05-19 18:30:51 - (not logged in) (*.*.*.*)> 331 Password required for user1
(000058) 2009-05-19 18:30:51 - (not logged in) (*.*.*.*)> PASS ******
(000058) 2009-05-19 18:30:51 - user1 (*.*.*.*)> 230 Logged on
(000058) 2009-05-19 18:30:51 - user1 (*.*.*.*)> CWD /
(000058) 2009-05-19 18:30:51 - user1 (*.*.*.*)> 250 CWD successful. "/" is current directory.
(000058) 2009-05-19 18:30:51 - user1 (*.*.*.*)> PWD
(000058) 2009-05-19 18:30:51 - user1 (*.*.*.*)> 257 "/" is current directory.
(000058) 2009-05-19 18:30:53 - user1 (*.*.*.*)> TYPE I
(000058) 2009-05-19 18:30:53 - user1 (*.*.*.*)> 200 Type set to I
(000058) 2009-05-19 18:30:54 - user1 (*.*.*.*)> PASV
(000058) 2009-05-19 18:30:54 - user1 (*.*.*.*)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (*.*.*.*.*.206)
(000058) 2009-05-19 18:30:54 - user1 (*.*.*.*)> STOR testfile.bmp
(000058) 2009-05-19 18:30:54 - user1 (*.*.*.*)> 150 Connection accepted
(000058) 2009-05-19 18:30:54 - user1 (*.*.*.*)> 226 Transfer OK
(000058) 2009-05-19 18:30:54 - user1 (*.*.*.*)> PASV
(000058) 2009-05-19 18:30:54 - user1 (*.*.*.*)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (*.*.*.*.*.207)
(000058) 2009-05-19 18:30:54 - user1 (*.*.*.*)> MLSD
(000058) 2009-05-19 18:30:55 - user1 (*.*.*.*)> 150 Connection accepted
(000058) 2009-05-19 18:30:55 - user1 (*.*.*.*)> 226 Transfer OK
(000057) 2009-05-19 18:31:12 - user1 (*.*.*.*)> disconnected.
```

This is my attempt, using FTP

```
(000060) 2009-05-19 18:34:17 - (not logged in) (*.*.*.*)> Connected, sending welcome message...
(000060) 2009-05-19 18:34:17 - (not logged in) (*.*.*.*)> 220 welcome...
(000060) 2009-05-19 18:34:22 - (not logged in) (*.*.*.*)> USER user1
(000060) 2009-05-19 18:34:22 - (not logged in) (*.*.*.*)> 331 Password required for user1
(000060) 2009-05-19 18:34:24 - (not logged in) (*.*.*.*)> PASS ******
(000060) 2009-05-19 18:34:24 - user1 (*.*.*.*)> 230 Logged on
(000060) 2009-05-19 18:34:33 - user1 (*.*.*.*)> CWD /
(000060) 2009-05-19 18:34:33 - user1 (*.*.*.*)> 250 CWD successful. "/" is current directory.
(000060) 2009-05-19 18:34:43 - user1 (*.*.*.*)> PWD
(000060) 2009-05-19 18:34:43 - user1 (*.*.*.*)> 257 "/" is current directory.
(000060) 2009-05-19 18:34:56 - user1 (*.*.*.*)> TYPE I
(000060) 2009-05-19 18:34:56 - user1 (*.*.*.*)> 200 Type set to I
(000060) 2009-05-19 18:35:03 - user1 (*.*.*.*)> PASV
(000060) 2009-05-19 18:35:03 - user1 (*.*.*.*)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (*.*.*.*.*.209)
(000060) 2009-05-19 18:35:19 - user1 (*.*.*.*)> STOR testfile.bmp
(000060) 2009-05-19 18:35:20 - user1 (*.*.*.*)> 425 Can't open data connection.
(000060) 2009-05-19 18:35:51 - user1 (*.*.*.*)> QUIT
(000060) 2009-05-19 18:35:51 - user1 (*.*.*.*)> 221 Goodbye
(000060) 2009-05-19 18:35:51 - user1 (*.*.*.*)> disconnected.
```

**What should I do to replicate FZ? What differs the two FTP clients?**

Answer (score 2):

It seems the MS ftp client does not support passive mode. Check [this](http://blogs.isaserver.org/pouseele/2006/11/09/about-the-microsoft-command-line-ftp-client/) out.

Comment: Just realised FileZilla can be used from the command line too. Can you try that? Or use the free ftp client mentioned in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

The MS FTP  doesn't work - I do the transfers now using [this utility](http://www.ncftp.com/) from the command line.

```
ncftpput -P 12345 -u user1 -p pass1 -F *.*.*.* / testfile.bmp
```